# Lightning component : Impossible to update value in form fields after resetting object value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

I have this lightning component that is a form for an object called newLine :

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="updateFacture" type="c:factureLinesUpdate"/>
      <aura:attribute name="newLine" type="ligne__c"
                    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'ligne__c',
                             'front_id': 0,
                             'Quantit_en_jours__c': 0,
                             'Prix_journalier__c ': 0,
                             'Sujet__c': '',
                             }"/>

                <lightning:input aura:id="factureform" label="Quantité en jour"
                                                    type="number"
                                                    step="0.5"
                                                    value="{!v.newLine.Quantit_en_jours__c}"
                                                    placeholder="ABC Co."/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="factureform" label="Description"
                                                    value="{!v.newLine.Sujet__c}"
                                                    placeholder="ABC Co."/>
               <lightning:input aura:id="factureform" label="Prix journalier"
                                                    type="number"
                                                    step="50"
                                                    value="{!v.newLine.Prix_journalier__c}"
                                                    placeholder="100"/>
              <lightning:button label="Save Line" 
                                class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                variant="brand"
                                onclick="{!c.saveLine}"/>

</aura:component>
```

When a newLine is saved, the controller action saveLine is called. This action should then resets the form after the line is saved :

```
({
    saveLine : function(component, event, helper) {
        var line = component.get("v.newLine");
        console.log("in saveline :", line.Description__c);
        var updateEvent = component.getEvent("updateFacture");
        component.set("v.saved", "true")
        updateEvent.setParams({ "line": line });
        updateEvent.fire();
       component.set("v.newLine", "{'sobjectType': 'ligne__c', 'Quantit_en_jours__c': 0, 'Prix_journalier__c ': 0,'Sujet__c': '', 'front_id':  0}");
    }
})
```

The form is rightly resetted to original values but then it is no longer possible to change the form values.
How do you correctly resets the object value ?

Comment: What is `front_id`, shouldn't it be `front_id__c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, the attribute is a native object, not a String. Do not include the quotes.

```
   component.set("v.newLine",
     { sobjectType: "ligne__c",
       Quantit_en_jours__c: 0,
       Prix_journalier__c: 0,
       Sujet__c: "",
       front_id__c:  0
     });
```

Also, double-check your code for spelling and case sensitivity. I fixed one presumably missing "__c", but you're going to need to pay more attention to your code.